# Second dialog box doesn't show

Tags: php, jquery, yii, modal-dialog

I'm developping with Yii framework. I create two dialog boxes in a Yii page to create some model. The first one pops up correctly, but the second one doesn't. 
I've written the view file. The `view.php` is as follow:

```
<?php
$this->menu=array(
    //array('label' => Yii::t('app', 'Publier à un contact'), 'url' => array('publierAContact', 'id_p'=> $model->id_publication, 'id_e' => $model->id_evenement)),
    array('label' => Yii::t('app', 'Publier à un contact'), 'url' =>'#','linkOptions' => array(
        'onclick' => "{publierAContact(); $('#dialogContact').dialog('open');}",
    )),
    array('label' => Yii::t('app', 'Publier à un groupe'), 'url' => '#', 'linkOptions' => array(
        'onclick' => "{publierAGroupe(); $('#dialogGroupe').dialog('open');}",
    ))
);

$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
        'id' => 'dialogContact',
        'options' => array(
            'title' => 'Publier à un contact',
            'autoOpen' => false,
            'modal' => true,
            'width' => 550,
            'height' => 200,
        ),
    ));
echo "<div class='divForForm'></div>";
$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
        'id' => 'dialogGroupe',
        'options' => array(
            'title' => 'Publier à un groupe',
            'autoOpen' => false,
            'modal' => true,
            'width' => 550,
            'height' => 200,
        ),
    ));

echo "<div class='divForForm'></div>";

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function publierAContact()
{
<?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
    'url' => array('Publication/PublierAContact', 'id_p'=>$id_p, 'id_e' =>$id_e),
    'data' => "js:$(this).serialize()",
    'type' => 'post',
    'dataType' => 'json',
    'success' => "function(data) 
        {
            if(data.status == 'failure')
            {
                $('#dialogContact div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                    //Here is the trick: on submit-> once again this function!
                $('#dialogContact div.divForForm form').submit(add);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#dialogContact div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                setTimeout(\"$('#dialogContact').dialog('close');refreshDisciplines();\", 1000);
                document.location.reload();
            }

        }"
));?>
return false;
}

function PublierAGroupe()
{
<?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
    'url' => array('Publication/PublierAGroupe', 'id_p' => $id_p, 'id_e' => $id_e),
    'data' => "js:$(this).serialize()",
    'type' => 'post',
    'dataType' => 'json',
    'success' => "function(data) 
        {
            if(data.status == 'failure')
            {
                $('#dialogGroupe div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                    //Here is the trick: on submit-> once again this function!
                $('#dialogGroupe div.divForForm form').submit(add);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#dialogGroupe div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                setTimeout(\"$('#dialogGroupe').dialog('close');refreshDisciplines();\", 1000);
                document.location.reload();
            }

        }"
));?>
return false;
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately,  my second dialog can not appear. Can somebody help me know what's wrong ?

**Edit :**

The function must be called properly :

```
'onclick' => "{PublierAGroupe(); $('#dialogContact').dialog('open');}",
```

as the function's identifier is `publierAGroupe`.

Comment: do you see any error in console log? if yes, let us know

Comment: A nice way to debug this thing would be to look at the source code and see if there might be some sort of duplicate inclusions from the widget itself (since you call it twice) which would lead to a javascript crash. Use web developer toolbar in firefox to see if there is an error in your javascript. Bonne chance!

Comment: Thank you all. It was case sensitive problem of the name of the javascript function : `PublierAGroupe()` instead of `publierAGroupe()`. Thanks again.